# Type of database to use Relational or NoSql for storing profile information

Tags: android, sql, database, database-design, nosql

I'm making an application for android which is used to store profile information of a user( FirstName, LastName, Email, Username, Password ). It will also store profile picture of the person. You can think of applications like WhatsApp, Viber Tango. There are many more like it

In my application, it needs to retrieve information(profile) of friends with whom I shared my profile which would also include their image. I have no idea whether to use relational or NoSQL database for it. How would one be better than another? Any ideas please.
(Note: I'm talking about database on the server which has all the profile information not the one in my phone. I know it's SQLite)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Well NoSQL isn't provided in the system api , so SQLite is the way to go for any DB operations.

Comment: Here is a tutorial that you can follow, and it contain an example of storing employees informations like ( first name , last name, email ...etc ) : http://bit.ly/1rqL9ZA

Comment: Maybe I explained question the wrong way. Profile information will be stored in database on server and I will retrieve that information. On the server side, what is the best database to use?

Comment: Ohh , ok , well it depends. I found that Mongo saves up a lot of time and it's fast http://java.dzone.com/articles/when-use-mongodb-rather-mysql

Answer (score 0):

This is a very big topic and is largely subjective, and should also depend on business priorities and many other considerations. While it may seem to require more upfront work to some developers, issues like security, scalability and performance need to be considered too.

In short however, I would suggest that given the nature of the data in your described scenario, which includes usernames and passwords and implies custom auth and has security ramifications, I would personally stick to a relational database.

After a quick search, I found these links useful to describe some of the breadth of the topic:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-dbpick/

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/big-data-analytics/10-things-it-architects-should-consider-when-choosing-data-storage-technologies/

This link briefly discusses some considerations of storing passwords with NoSQL:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20103/store-user-passwords-in-nosql-database

Hope that helps!